# Quick Action - Visualforce - Header missing after Summer 16 (Bug)

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, header-bar, quickaction

I have a Visualforce page that was created prior the Summer '15 release and was being used as a target of a quick action for SF1 on a custom object.

Everything has been working fine until the Summer '16 release.

Around the time of the Summer 16 release (not sure if it was that or a patch release) the Quick Action Header

[image]

**disappeared**. The page did not have the `showQuickActionVfHeader` as a part of the page (supposed to default to true anyway).

Attempts to get it back failed. The following was tried:

1. Add the `showQuickActionVfHeader=true` to the page
2. Delete all contents of the page and replace it with the code from [TrailHead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1_actions_object)
3. Changed the API version to 37.

Even with the exact code from trailhead it still is missing

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to save someone else the headache here is how I resolved it. (Keep in mind that the API of the original page was updated to 37.0 and still did not work)

I got to thinking, if the code pasted directly from trailhead failed was it a bug in the org?

1. Created a new VF page and Quick action using the trailhead module mentioned in the question.
2. Added it to the opportunity
3. Spun it up - **bingo** the page loaded fine with the quick action header visible.

Hmmmm... Its the same code as the original page, same everything, a copy and paste. Why does the original page still have the Action Header missing.

I said self - repeat the process with the problematic page.

**Resolution**

1. Deleted references to the problematic page
2. Copied the page code to a text editor (to save it)
3. Deleted the VF page from the org
4. Created a new VF page
5. Pasted the code (Exact same as original) into it
6. Save it
7. Recreated the quick actions and placed them on the page layouts

**Boom** page now works as expected.

Frustrating because the versioning meant nothing. the page was at API version 32 which was prior to the `showQuickActionVfHeader` being available. V37.0 broke pages created on previous versions.

its not often that something requires a complete deletion to resolve the issue and often it is not something we think about doing.

Hope this saves someone else some time and frustration.